# what is the maximum length of variable name in arduino?

Tags: arduino

I would like to know :

- Is there a maximum length of variable name for arduino ?
- If yes, does it depend of model of arduino used (uno, mega2560, etc...) ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what a compiler is? Do you know what is uploaded to your Arduino?

Comment: no, I don't know  at all how it work.... I just start to learn about it, I will have a look about it, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, if there's any, it is over a megabyte (!!).

That's pretty big, but variable names are meant for your compiler. The compiler translates variable names into addresses, and that address will be 2 or 4 bytes. The compiler runs on your PC where there is plenty of memory, and your Arduino just deals with the address.

Since the compiler runs on your PC, the name length doesn't depend on the Arduino model.